# Markdown + LaTeX + Jekyll (Github Pages) = HTML?

Tags: latex, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, mathjax

I'm trying to use Github pages to both host my source files (strictly markdown with LaTeX equations) and manage the equation rendering when hosting the actual webpage. If I understand this process correctly, github uses **Jekyll** to statically generate the website, I guess converting all my .md into .html, so I don't have to.

I've read so many posts at this point indicating that I just have to [include some lines in my html to run some javascript](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted) to use **MathJax**. I don't know javascript or html so most of the answers seem unclear to me.

Does anyone have a **I need a barebones index.md hosted on github.io that renders MathJax**.

I've tried:

Creating files in **layouts/default.html**

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

In **_config.yml**:

`usemathjax : true` in `_config.yml`, an

In the __*.md__itself (YAML Front matter):

```
---
usemathjax : true
---
```

My website is [here](https://alaut.github.io/) with [this](https://alaut.github.io/space_charge.html) page showing an html rendered from the markdown automatically via github, the other pages I generated the html locally in VS Code which doesn't scale properly on mobile and not what I want if github can just manage it directly. The source code is [here](https://github.com/alaut/alaut.github.io) for my repo.

Comment: To clarify, do you just want to know how to add MathJax to your `html`/webpage so that it will render your LaTeX?

Comment: i want to know how to configure __Github pages__ such that it will correctly interpret my markdown files with delimited equations, and generate the appropriate html files with equations rendered in MathJax or preferably KaTeX.